# Why disconnection is happeing after running df.head

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1.info()
```

`df = pd.DataFrame([[x for x in df1['final_resp']]])`

df['resp']

```
[['Office/work], ['car/scooter'], ['Sometimes'], ['Saw scooters'], ['Cost-effective'],  ['31-40'], ['Salaried], ['PhD degree']]
[['Park/College], ['scooter'], ['Sometimes'], ['Saw scooters'], ['Cost-effective'],  ['31-40'], ['Salaried], ['Bachelors']]
```

The resp values has to split and and put in to next column

Every time my connection is getting droped after running  `df.head(1)`

My output is all the column is repeating around number of columns which wrong means `[['Office/work], ['car/scooter'], ['Sometimes'], ['Saw scooters'], ['Cost-effective'],  ['31-40'], ['Salaried], ['PhD degree']]` repeating 2000 times because that is my shape of matrix

Comment: which connection?

Comment: connection with server because my `df = pd.DataFrame([[x for x in df1['final_resp']]])
` is adding 2000 columns of same data

Comment: @ignoring_gravity my split code is not working `['Office/work], ['car/scooter'], ['Sometimes'], ['Saw scooters'], ['Cost-effective'],  ['31-40'], ['Salaried], ['PhD degree']]` has to be in separate columns

Comment: Best to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example